# Existence of abelian group which has no “square-root” but whose “cube” has a “square-root”

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Does there exist an abelian group $G$ such that $G \ncong H \times H$ for every abelian group $H$ but $G \times G \times G \cong K \times K$ for some abelian group $K$ ?

Also see [Existence of topological space which has no "square-root" but whose "cube" has a "square-root"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051780/existence-of-topological-space-which-has-no-square-root-but-whose-cube-has-a)

Comment: [Structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_abelian_groups) clearly shows that such a group cannot be finitely generated.

Comment: @RobArthan: no ... I do mean what I wrote ...

Comment: @Crostul: I'm not so sure about the torsion part ...

Comment: OK. I just wanted to check that you didn't mean "some".  "any" would be more idiomatic than "every" in this context,