# Can different topological spaces have the same square?

Tags: general-topology

For topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, is it possible that $X \times X$ and $Y \times Y$ are homeomorphic, but $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic?

(I poked around with finite spaces, and manifolds, and the Cantor set, without seeing any examples.)

This was inspired by [Existence of topological space which has no “square-root” but whose “cube” has a “square-root”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051780/existence-of-topological-space-which-has-no-square-root-but-whose-cube-has-a). Cartesian product makes the proper class of topological spaces (up to homeomorphism) into a large abelian monoid, so here's a bonus question: what is known about the structure of this monoid? For example, the dogbone space shows that it is not cancellative. Does it have torsion in the sense that sometimes $X^n \not\cong X$ but $X^{n + 1} \cong X$?

Comment: It's not possible for finite spaces, by my argument at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269542/when-x-times-y-cong-x-times-z-implies-y-cong-z-in-the-category-of-finit/269545#269545.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the Whitehead manifold.  See: http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1960__88__131_0.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold

Comment: The existence of such spaces $X, Y$ is what's used in Mike Miller 's example, see his answer in the linked question. But Whitehead manifold would also do the job.

Comment: As for the "torsion" examples, see references in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3

Comment: @MoisheCohen Interesting, for OP's sake I will observe that there exists a functor from groups to spaces, given by constructing a simplicial complex called "$BG$" whose $n$-simplices are labelled by sequences $[g_1, \cdots, g_n]$ of elements of $G$ (and the gluings involve multiplications), and $B(G \times H) = BG \times BH$. In particular, functoriality means that if $G$ and $H$ are homeomorphic, so are $BG$ and $BH$, and conversely (if $BG \cong BH$ then $G \cong H$ by looking at fundamental groups). So if $A \cong A^3 \neq A^2$, then $BA \cong (BA)^3 \neq (BA)^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copying part of my answer to [this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150793/if-g-times-g-cong-h-times-h-then-is-g-cong-h):

> Whether two (a) topological spaces, (b) metric spaces, or (c) groups $A$ and $B$, with isomorphic squares, are necessarily isomorphic, was Problem 77 (of Ulam) in [the Scottish book](http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/pdf/ks-szkocka/ks-szkocka3ang.pdf). The following information is from the commentaries on Problem 77, by Mauldin for (a) and (b) and by Kaplansky for (c), in [*The Scottish Book: Mathematics from the Scottish Café*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3764330457), R. Daniel Mauldin, ed., 1981.
>   
> Mauldin gives a bibliography of 17 items for parts (a) and (b). The first counterexample for part (a), as well as a positive answer for two-dimensional compact manifolds, was given by R. H. Fox, On a problem of S. Ulam concerning Cartesian products, Fund. Math. 34 (1947), 278-287. The first counterexample to part (b) was given by G. Fournier, On a problem of S. Ulam, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 29 (1971), 622. Mauldin writes (in 1981):
>   
> "However, it is open whether there is an affirmative solution to (b) in the case that $A$ and $B$ are complete metric spaces. In fact, part (b) is open in the case where $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be compact."

Comment: I deleted my silly comment, which parsed (b) as "metrizable".

Comment: For completeness: I see the Fox paper at http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm34/fm34128.pdf, and another example from Marjanović and Vučemilović at https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/106394/CommentatMathUnivCarol_026-1985-3_11.pdf.